# Get Linux file descriptor of FileChannel

Tags: java, linux, java-nio

Is there a way to get the Linux file descriptor for an opened FileChannel?

I need it to call `mount.fuse -o fd=...` (for implementing FUSE).

As a hacky workaround, I'm doing:

```
var pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
var fd = Files.list(Path.of("/proc/"+pid+"/fd")).count();
var fc = FileChannel.open(path);
System.out.println("file descriptor: " + fd);
```

Note that two file descriptors appear. One for `path` and another `socket`. I'm using the first one. What is the socket for?

Comment: There is no socket in this code.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, that’s what’s strange. It shows up in `/proc/…/fd` after opening filechannel.

Comment: So you open a socket in some other piece of code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the file descriptor from a `RandomAccessFile`:

```
long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
long guessedFd = Files.list(Path.of("/proc/"+pid+"/fd")).count();

var file = new java.io.RandomAccessFile(FUSE_DEVICE_PATH.toFile(), "rw");
FileChannel fc = file.getChannel(); // Use FileChannel for fast NIO
var javaFd = file.getFD();
try {
    Field f = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    var trueFd = (int) f.get(javaFd);
    return trueFd;
}
catch (InaccessibleObjectException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    return guessedFd;
}
```

On Java 11+ you will the jvm option `--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED` at startup. Tested on Java 18.

---

In Java 17 you can use `SharedSecrets` instead of reflection:

```
FileDescriptor javaFd = ...
try {
    int trueFd = jdk.internal.access.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().get(javaFd);
    return trueFd;
}
catch (IllegalAccessError e) {
    return guessedFd;
}
```

You will need to add `--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.access=ALL-UNNAMED` when compiling and running. See [for Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68058292/1151521).